# mv equivalent rsync command

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, mv

i'm trying to move folders to another folders **using command line**, with overwrite if already exists, but i got  error "Is a directory" when using mv..

example:

```
mv src/test/ dest/
```

there are many files and folders on src/test/, there are also some files and some folders on dest/

and i want files and folders on dest/ **replaced** with files and folder from src/test/ **if exists**, example:

```
src/test/bla/boo replaces dest/bla/boo
src/test/bla/bla/boo replaces dest/bla/bla/boo
```

also, **everytime one file transfer completed, that one file deleted** from src/test/

and **overall transfer progress bar** would be fine..

what rsync flag should i use to make this happend?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The following command line should achieve what you want:

```
$ rsync -a --progress --remove-source-files src/test/ dest
```

Comment: but it doesn't do "everytime one file transfer completed, that one file deleted from src/test/"

Comment: Really? `--remove-source-files` should do exactly that.

Comment: nope XD sorry, it does.. my mistake..
thanks ^^

Comment: Well that's not exactly what `mv` does. `mv` a file to another directory in the same partition requires no copy at all, while this `rsync` equivalent will takes a lot time copying the file then delete the source file.

Comment: @yegle is right. If you really want to move files within a physical(?) drive, `mv` should be a LOT faster. If you want to move to a different drive such as external HDD, USB stick etc. then the command above is to be preferred to `mv` I think.